# Create a promise with a dynamic timeout

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have created a `Promise` in oder to get the duration of one file whenever has finished its synthesising.

I believe that the solution is really inefficient, since I set a `timeout` regardless when the task has finished so probably I will just waste time each time I call the method:

```
polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            else {
                var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(data.AudioStream);
                var arrayBuffer = uInt8Array.buffer;
                var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);

                var urlAudioFile = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                var audio = new Audio(urlAudioFile);
                audio.type = 'audio/wav';
                getAudioFileDurationAsync(audio);

            };
        });

 function getAudioFileDurationAsync(audio) {
        let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve("done!")
            }, 3000);
        });

        promise.then(
            result => {
                console.log(audio.duration);
            }, 
            error => console.log(error) // doesn't run
        );
    };
```

Obviously, after `3000ms` I get the duration of the file, but I would like to do it as soon as the file has finished synthesising. How could I do it?

Comment: why do you need a timeout here? Do you want to `reject` the promise if processing is too slow (more than 3sec)?

Comment: No, I just want to get the value of audio.duration once is available

Comment: then see @Argee's answer, it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, it seems to be possible to get the duration :

```
var audioElement = new Audio('car_horn.wav');
audioElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', () => {
  let duration = audioElement.duration;
  // The duration variable now holds the duration (in seconds) of the audio clip 
})
```

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

is that working for you?

Basically you just need to wrap the code you want to be notified about with a Promise. If you have a callback function just like in your example, all you have to do is let it resolve from within that callback.

```js
const audioFileDuration = (params) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(data.AudioStream);
    var arrayBuffer = uInt8Array.buffer;
    var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);

    var urlAudioFile = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var audio = new Audio(urlAudioFile);
    audio.type = 'audio/wav';

    resolve(audio.duration)
  });
});

audioFileDuration(params).then(duration => console.log(duration))
```

Comment: When I run it in my code, the message which is printed is NaN, meaning that there is still no file.

Answer (score 0):

SetTimeOut acts as the maximum duration[TTL] you want to wait for the function.
You can try resolving the promise in two flows

1. when timeout reached of 3000ms
2. as soon as you get the duration of file after it has finished its synthesising.

whichever of the above flows completes early will resolve the promise and your code could proceed further not waiting for second resolve.

Make sure you clear timeout if the second process(getting duration) is finished earlier